# In Firebase how do I detect if a reference is synchronized between local and server?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing a chat application and I want to know if is there any way to find out when a reference (created while offline) it's synchronized between the local data store and the server.

Comment: You could check to see if the firebase client is connected or has connected recently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38893145/how-to-know-if-data-are-retrieved-from-local-storage-or-server-storage?rq=1

Comment: @dazza5000 Thanks, I was expecting something like datasnapshot.isSync coming from firebase when receiving data from a listener. But apparently I will have to track that on my own...

Answer (score 0):

In your application you get data from cache always. So there is no case of data is coming from cache or network. When Firebase Sync to your app first time it creates cache and maintain until phone is not restarted or you have not cleared your app from task manager. It always maintains a cache and your app gets data from the cache.

How they have implemented this stuff they do not have revealed.

If you have any doubt still feel free to ask.